# How to split a Scala script into multiple files

Tags: scala, scripting

Used as a scripting language, does Scala have some sort of include directive, or is there a way to launch a script from an other script ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scala` command has the `:load filename` command to load a Scala file interactively.  Alternatively the `scala` command's `-i filename` argument can be used to preload the file.

Answer (score 2):

As of beginning of 2013, there seems to be no built-in support for multiple-file scripts.

There's one guy that implemented `#include` support for **non-interactive** scala scripts, by assembling and compiling the files in a prior stage (have not tried it yet).

Here is the blog post about it:

http://www.crosson.org/2012/01/simplifying-scala-scripts-adding.html

And the git repository:

https://github.com/dacr/bootstrap

I hope this, or something along the lines, get official some day, since the `-i filename` scala switch seems to apply only for the *interactive* console.

Until then a proper scripting language, like Ruby, might still remain the best option.

Comment: "Until then a proper scripting language, like Ruby, might still remain the best option." Perhaps. Though what I am looking for is way to write simple, type safe scripts.

Answer (score 2):

[Ammonite](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/) is an option. It implements scala (plus extensions) including `import` in scripts.